# Identify all commits made in a push

Tags: git, teamcity

I´m configuring a TeamCity server and I need to know how to identify all files committed in a single push.

Ex.:

- User commit 1:

  - file1.c
  - file2.c
- User commig 2:

  - file1.c
  - fileX.c
  - fileY.c

I need to group all these files to make 1 build for this "push" command. There is a git command to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you `git fetch` and then `git merge`, git will display a list of all the files that changed in that merge (for all commits that were in that merge). Does that help?

Comment: Do you need to know the total collection of changed files?  or specifically which files were changed by each commit when there is more than one such commit?

Comment: @Wolf, I need to know the total collection of changed files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display the git log and work with the results:

list the last commit:

```
git log --name-status -p -1

result: 
commit d1bc9d55024e4e3e6acc087ba223bd7951b555fa
            Author: unknown <johndoe>
            Date:   Wed Oct 7 16:20:27 2015 -0300

                           task1000 commit message here...

            M           file1.c
            M           file2.c
```

now, list all commits with "task1000" in message:

```
git log --name-status --grep="task1000"

result:
            commit d1bc9d55024e4e3e6acc087ba223bd7951b555fa
            Author: unknown <johndoe>
            Date:   Wed Oct 7 16:20:27 2015 -0300

                           task1000 commit message here...

            M           file1.c
            M           file2.c

            commit 998a74eaa752f6c98c32ec9a412b219afb7cc891
            Author: unknown <johndoe>
            Date:   Wed Oct 7 16:19:56 2015 -0300

                           task1000 more one commit for this task..

            M           file1.c
            M           fileX.c
            M           fileY.c
```

Now you have to work with this result.

You need to be watching for every commit in your server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$ git diff --name-only <your commit range>
```

For example,

```
$ git diff --name-only HEAD~3..HEAD
config/sidekiq.yml
deploy/before_migrate.rb
deploy/before_restart.rb
```

You can use it in `post-receive` hook (as [said in the docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy)) as following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

$oldrev  = ARGV[1]
$newrev  = ARGV[2]

`git diff --name-only #{$oldrev}..#{$newrev} > listing.txt`
```

Comment: unfortunately I don´t have the commit range.

Comment: What information do you have? Is that a post-push hook?

Comment: No, it will run in another server, the Teamcity server.

Comment: So someone pushes to the Teamcity server and you want to post-process there, right?

Comment: The Teamcity server is only for build my dlls. The git server will be in a place like github or gitlab. So, when someone push to github, the teamcity needs to know that this happens and what was committed.

Comment: Well, then I guess my solution should work. You should install it as a post-receive hook on your github/gitlab server and modify the script to send it to your Teamcity server via some API.